# How to set up a Vue app with Okta auth with Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, okta, vue-composition-api

I am setting up a basic Vue authentication app using Okta, based on the following: https://github.com/okta/okta-vue. I am attempting to convert the logic that handles routing and signin redirecting from Options API to Composition API. In other words, the login/logout functionality in App.vue, which is currently written like this:

```js
    async login () {
      await this.$auth.signInWithRedirect()
      this.$router.push('/protected')
    },
    async logout () {
      await this.$auth.signOut()
    }

https://github.com/okta/okta-vue#show-login-and-logout-buttons
```

Would probably look something like this in Composition API (I think):

```js
    setup() {
      const router = useRouter()
      
      const login = () => {
        this.$auth.signInWithRedirect()
      }

      const logout = () => {
        this.$auth.signOut()
      }

      return {login, logout, router}
    }
```

However, I'm not sure how to change `this.$auth.signInWithRedirect()` and `this.$auth.signOut()` to work with Composition API, since $auth doesn't appear to be an accepted property. How can I set up the Okta methods `signInWithRedirect()` and `signOut()` to work with composition API? I'm new to Composition API and Vue in Typescript. Feedback is appreciated!

Here is the rest of the code below:

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-if='authState && authState.isAuthenticated' @click='logout' id='logout-button'> Logout </button>
    <button v-else @click='login' id='login-button'> Login </button>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'app',
    setup() {
      const router = useRouter()
      
      const login = () => {
        this.$auth.signInWithRedirect()
        router.push('/protected')
      }

      const logout = () => {
        this.$auth.signOut()
      }

      return {login, logout, router}
    }
  
})
</script>
```

main.ts

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'
import OktaVue from '@okta/okta-vue'

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
    issuer: 'https://{dev-id}.okta.com/oauth2/default',
    clientId: '{clientId}',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/login/callback',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
  })

  const app = createApp(App)
  app.use(OktaVue, { oktaAuth })
  app.use(router)
  app.mount('#app')
```

router/index.ts

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import { LoginCallback } from '@okta/okta-vue'
import { navigationGuard } from '@okta/okta-vue'
import Protected from '../views/Protected.vue'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  { 
    path: '/login/callback', 
    component: LoginCallback 
  },
  {
    path: '/protected',
    name: 'Protected',
    component: Protected,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach(navigationGuard)

export default router
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `okta-vue` plugin configures a [global property](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) named `$auth` (which enables `this.$auth` usage in the Options API). The property's [value is actually the same `oktaAuth` instance passed into the plugin](https://github.com/okta/okta-vue/blob/4a5ebf6/src/okta-vue.ts#L151) via `app.use(OktaVue, { oktaAuth })` (i.e., `this.$auth` is set to `oktaAuth`).

In the Composition API, you could access the app's global properties via `getCurrentInstance()`:

```html
// MyComponent.vue
<script lang="ts">
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
import type { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'

export default {
  setup() {
    const oktaAuth = getCurrentInstance()!!.appContext.app.config.globalProperties.$auth as OktaAuth
    const login = () => oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect()
    const logout = () => oktaAuth.signOut()
    ⋮
  }
}
</script>
```

Another approach is to move the `oktaAuth` instance into a shared file that could be imported when needed, given that `oktaAuth` is the same as the `$auth` global property:

```js
// auth.ts
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js'

export const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
  issuer: `https://${process.env.VUE_APP_OKTA_DOMAIN}/oauth2/default`,
  clientId: `${process.env.VUE_APP_OKTA_CLIENT_ID}`,
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
  pkce: true,
})
```

```js
// main.ts
import OktaVue from '@okta/okta-vue'
import { oktaAuth } from './auth' 

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(OktaVue, { oktaAuth })
⋮
```

```html
// MyComponent.vue
<script lang="ts">
import { oktaAuth } from './auth' 

export default {
  setup() {
    const login = () => oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect()
    const logout = () => oktaAuth.signOut()
    ⋮
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-cli-okta-demo)

Comment: Moving the oktaAuth instance into a shared file is nice and clean. Excellent solution.